# Reload collection view with new data IOS7

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, reloaddata

Hi I am developing small IOS application and I am new to IOS development. In my application I am using collection view to display my data. What i am doing I am fetching data from my server and then displaying in my UIView controller. Here is my code looks like

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

// call for fetching data from server 
}


// My collection view methods
-(NSInteger) numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
return 1;
}

-(NSInteger) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:     (NSInteger)section
 {
return [_channelArray count];
}

-(UICollectionViewCell *) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView    cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

cell.image = // set image from channel array.
return cell;
}



// callback for m web service call 
-(void) didReceiveSubscriberChannelList:(SubscriberChannelListDataModel *)subscriberChannelListInfo
 {

_channelList = subscriberChannelListInfo;
_channelArray = subscriberChannelListInfo.chanellist;
[collectionView reloadData];
 }
```

Above code works with static data. But now I want to display my server data. My reload data not working. How to do this. Need Help. Thank you.

Comment: call your webservice method in viewWillAppear methods : didReceiveSubscriberChannelList

Comment: @DivyaBhalodiya I am not getting your point.

Comment: " callback for m web service call "  put in viewWillAppear

Comment: Put `NSLog(@"channelArray: %@", _channelArray);` right after `_channelArray = subscriberChannelListInfo.chanellist;` and tell us what you see in the terminal while debugging.

Comment: @dasdom It contains values. So its not empty. Can you please explain what is the best way to do web calls in iphone

Comment: A lot of people use AFNetworking: https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking. I tend to use `NSURLSession`. Here is how I do it in most cases: http://dasdev.de/2014/04/02/how-i-do-basic-networking/

Comment: @dasdom thank you for your quick replay. Will go through those links and let you know whether works or not.

Comment: @dasdom my problem is not regarding network calls its regarding updating data in collection view or how to bind new data with collection view. If you have any idea regarding this please let me know . I am new for IOS.

Comment: But, if the the array contains values you should investigate why they aren't shown in the collection view. Set breakpoints in `cellForItemAtIndexPath` and look into the data source. There is some thing wrong. I believe the data from the server looks different than you local data.

Comment: Show us the code for `// set image from channel array.`

Comment: @dasdom Thank you for response. I have solve this problem. I put [collectionview reload] inside my call back. Actually it taking too much time to form my collection view. SO I fetch my data from server.After that it takes some time to form collection view and then display it. Thank you for your Help. :)

Answer (score 2):

Did you consider put the callback method data in a block?

```
// callback for m web service call 
-(void) didReceiveSubscriberChannelList:(SubscriberChannelListDataModel *)subscriberChannelListInfo
{
      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
       _channelList = subscriberChannelListInfo;
       _channelArray = subscriberChannelListInfo.chanellist;
       [collectionView reloadData];
      });
}
```

This way, when the callback returns it will reload the data in the **main thread** (the UI thread)